# Compare column A to colum B PHP

Tags: php

[image]

I've made simple two columns using while loop and I want to compare each rows of these columns.

I've made a condition that when a row from column A matches a row from column B, the font will be colored in blue.

But the problem is, my "if condition" is comparing them by row, which means 07:30 to 09:00, 08:00 to 09:30, 08:30 to 10:00 and so on... I would like to compare all the variables from column A to column B.

```
$time = strtotime("08:30:00");
$timeStop = strtotime("17:30:00");

$start = strtotime("07:00:00");
$end = strtotime("16:00:00");

while ($start<$end || $time<$timeStop) {
    $start = strtotime('+30 minutes', $start);
    $time = strtotime('+30 minutes', $time);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    if ($time==$start) {
        echo "<td style='color : blue'>".date('H:i', $start)."</td>";
    }else{
        echo "<td>".date('H:i', $start)."</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>".date('H:i', $time)."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Almost all of the values in col A appear _somewhere_ in col B.  So what's really the point?  You're basically just changing the color of all but 4 in each column?

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes. I'd just like to change the color of all the rows from column A that matches row from column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this basically just boils down to checking the current Column A time against the entire range of Column B.  To do this, you need to set a column B start time variable that doesn't change (you already have one for the column B end time).  Then you simply check and see if your column A time in each loop iteration is anywhere between the start and end of column B.

```
// we need to always be able to reference this time
$timeBegin = strtotime("08:30:00");
$time = $timeBegin;
$timeStop = strtotime("17:30:00");


$start = strtotime("07:00:00");
$end = strtotime("16:00:00");

while ($start<$end || $time<$timeStop) {
    $matched = false;

    // check if the current column A time is anywhere between the first and last time in Column B
    if($start >= $timeBegin && $start <= $timeStop)
    {
        $matched = true;
    }

    $start = strtotime('+30 minutes', $start);
    $time = strtotime('+30 minutes', $time);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>";

    if ($matched) {
        echo "<td style='color : blue'>".date('H:i', $start)."</td>";
    }else{
        echo "<td>".date('H:i', $start)."</td>";
    }

    echo "<td>".date('H:i', $time)."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the values for both columns in an array first. And then in the loop that turns it into a table, you can use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$time = strtotime("08:30:00");
$timeStop = strtotime("17:30:00");


$start = strtotime("07:00:00");
$end = strtotime("16:00:00");

$columnA = [];
$columnB = [];

while ($start<$end || $time<$timeStop) {
    $start = strtotime('+30 minutes', $start);
    $time =  strtotime('+30 minutes', $time);
    array_push($columnA, $start); //Store all possible values in an array first.
    array_push($columnB,$time);
}


for($i = 0; $i<count($columnA); $i++) {
    $start = $columnA[$i];
    $time = $columnB[$i];
    //And then iterate over those arrays again.

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>";

    if (in_array($start, $columnB)) { //And now we can check if it exists in B at all!
        echo "<td style='color : blue'>".date('H:i', $start)."</td>";
    }else{
        echo "<td>".date('H:i', $start)."</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>".date('H:i', $time)."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer and time.  I'll save your code.